# How to cancel arrow-kt IO?

Tags: arrow-kt

Is is possible to cancel an (Arrow-Kt) `IO`?

In `RxJava` whenever I do `observable.subscribe({ // handle success },{ // some errohandling })`, I am given a `Disposable` which I could call `Disposable.dispose()` on.

Similar with coroutines, doing `coroutineScope.launch { // Some suspending function }` returns a `Job` to which I could call, `Job.cancel()` and even call `coroutineScope.cancel()` to cancel all coroutines in the scope.

I am looking for the same thing with IO. How could I achieve the same thing in `IO`? I am only calling `IO.unsafeRunAsyncCancellable { // Some Operations }` but I can't seem to find a way to cancel it if I have to. Although it returns a `Disposable`, I don't exactly know what to do with it as it is just a type alias for `() -> Unit`.

Can someone guide me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself `unsafeRunAsyncCancellable` returns `Disposable`. It's indeed a typealias for `() -> Unit`, which is the same as `Disposable#dispose` froom RxJava. It's a function that takes no arguments, and returns `Unit`.
Upon invocation it cancels the `IO`. Since it's simply a function something like `CompositeDisposable` from RxJava becomes simple function composition.

Further more, we also have integrations for KotlinX Coroutines structured concurrency in the case you'd like to interopt with that library. In that case you can use the [KotlinX integration module](https://next.arrow-kt.io/docs/integrations/kotlinxcoroutines/) which is currently in SNAPSHOT but is expected to be released this month.

I hope that answers your questions :)